# 80s children TV series where a chest in the attic was a portal to another world

Tags: story-identification, tv

This 80s children TV series was probably British, but I'm not sure about that.

There were two kids (brother and sister) and a chest in the attic. The chest was a portal to another world. In that world there was a forest and some puppet animals. I remember one of them being a talking python.

It was live action with puppets.

Comment: This is a nice description but is there anything else you can remember and [edit] in? For example, can you remember the plot of any specific episode? Was it live action or cartoon? (I assume live action because of the puppets but maybe not).

Comment: May not be an exact match, but allowing for the amount of time that's passed since the 80s, if you look at the early series of T-Bag (esp. Wonders in Letterland) could it be one of those? See http://www.t-room.co.uk/TheSeries.php

Comment: @AJM, Sorry it's not T-Bag. It's more realistic (to an extent) with a more complex set, or even a location shooting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for *[Blizzard Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blizzard_Island)*. To borrow from the IMDB summary for *[The Argon Quest](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099055/)*, which was a TV movie cobbled together from the first few episodes:

> Siblings Tracy and Wayne find a mysterious artifact that teleports them to Blizzard Island, a magical place full of strange creatures. They discover that the island is slowly dying, and the only way to save it is by finding and waking up the giant Argon. However, the evil witch Sidney won't have any of that...

They find the artifact in a chest in the attic, which comes from their father, a sailor lost at sea. One of the first puppets we encounter is a green puppet snake with a top hat in a forest.
[image: Sir Python and Molcaster in the forest]

### First episode of *Blizzard Island*

Found with a search for `80s tv series puppets brother sister attic portal`, which led to [this discussion forum](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/18.193855-I-need-help-remembering-this-T-V-show), where someone was looking for it. You can find more information on [Terry Angus's site](http://www.anguspuppets.com/Blizzard_Island.html).

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202964/old-kids-show-from-the-80s-about-two-kids-with-a-magical-compass-that-took-them/203030#203030, but that's not such a bad thing. :) It means more people are looking for it.

Comment: That's it! Thanks FuzzyBoots